# react bootstrap tabs custom class not working

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, tabs, react-bootstrap

I use react bootstrap `tabs` component but when i use a custom css within this `nav-link` with a custom parent class indicator its not working.

```
<Tabs
       defaultActiveKey="signup_renter"
       id="uncontrolled-tab-example"
       className="mb-3 approval-details-tab"
     >
     <Tab eventKey="signup_renter" title="About Car">
        <div className="signup-renter">
            this is signup renter tab            
        </div>
     </Tab>
     <Tab eventKey="signup_host" title="Details">
         <div className="signup-host">
            this is signup host tab          
        </div>
     </Tab>
    </Tabs>
```

Here is my css parent indicator:

```
.approval-details-tab > .nav-tabs .nav-link.active::before {
  content: "";
  background: #524eb7;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 63% !important;
}
```

I use `.approval-details-tab` class as a parent class of `nav-tabs` but without parent class it works. but i need a parent class for separate design.

Answer (score 0):

From the [React-bootstrap documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction):

> Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included CSS. However, some stylesheet is required to use these components.

> How and which Bootstrap styles you include is up to you, but the simplest way is to include the latest styles from the CDN.

> CDN link: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

Add CDN at index.html file inside  tag like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

Now, to override any class of `react-bootstrap', you have to use "!important" on your custom css. If you want to override the background color, use "!important" beside that css property.

Example:

```
.approval-details-tab{
   background: #524eb7 !important;
}
```

To get more clear understanding of your problem, please mention which css-property you want to override of a bootstrap class. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In React, the parent-children relationship is a bit complicated. Although a component in React seemed to be the direct child of another component, when translated to normal HTML, it doesn't. For example, take a look at this code

```
<div className="parent">
    <Tabs className="children"> 
       some other components inside
    </Tabs>
</div>
```

Does `div` the direct parent of the component `Tabs`? It is not. The above code, when being translated to normal HTML component would look roughly like this

```
<div className="parent">
   <div>
     <div className="children">
       some other components inside
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the element that bears the className `children` is no longer the direct child of the parent component. That is why in React, it is not a good idea to style components using parent-direct children relationship.

If you  just want to do this way of styling because you want to avoid naming conflict, you can try out [CSS Module](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet)

If you want to read the detail on how the `Tabs` component behave, you can read the [source code](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/Tabs.tsx#L141)